# Parcel: @parcel/transformer-postcss doesn't do the transpilation?

Tags: parcel

In a `.css` file I import, I have

1. some [custom media queries](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-plugins/tree/main/plugins/postcss-custom-media#postcss-custom-media-) and
2. a weird css property syntax, where the property is preceded with a star, like this: `*zoom: 1` (I can't avoid using this syntax because it's in [turretcss](https://turretcss.com/) dist file)

My Parcel version: `2.11.0`.

My `.postcssrc` is this:

```json
{
  "plugins": {
    "postcss-preset-env": {
      "stage": 2,
      "features": {
        "custom-media-queries": true
      }
    },
    "postcss-remove-declaration": {
      "remove": {
        ".clearfix": "*zoom"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

1. `postcss-preset-env`'s `custom-media-queries` feature should remove the custom media queries from `1`
2. [`postcss-remove-declaration`](https://github.com/andrewvasilchuk/postcss-remove-declaration) should remove the property with the weird syntax from `2`

My `.parcelrc` is this:

```json
{
    "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
    "transformers": {
        "*.{css,pcss}": ["@parcel/transformer-postcss", "@parcel/transformer-css"],
    }
}
```

which really duplicates what's in `@parcel/config-default` anyway.

I suppose, this setup should mean that `@parcel/transformer-postcss` is run before `@parcel/transformer-css`, transforming the `.css` by removing `1` and `2` from above and then passing the transformed css to `@parcel/transformer-css`.

However, what I get in practice is these warnings from `@parcel/transformer-css`:

[image: parcel warnings]

and this error from it:

[image: parcel error]

Which must mean that none of the PostCSS stuff has been executed.

I know that in Parcel the way you remove custom media queries is by [configuring `@parcel/transformer-css` in `package.json`](https://parceljs.org/languages/css/#custom-media-queries). But I use PostCSS here just to demonstrate the behavior.

Am I getting something wrong in my description of how the transformers should work? How do I get this to work properly?

Thanks in advance!